# How to handle servlet exceptions in Rest Web Services Java using error-pages in web.xml?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, web.xml, servletexception

I want to handle Servlet Exceptions in my rest web services.I am using error-pages tag in web.xml file but still am not able to catch the exceptions.Where should I place my ErrorHandler.java file.Below is my web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
   <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- servlet mappings -->
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/ErrorHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type >
   <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

And Here is my sample Exception handler code-

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class ErrorHandler extends HttpServlet {

   // Method to handle GET method request.
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // Analyze the servlet exception       
      Throwable throwable = (Throwable)
      request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
      Integer statusCode = (Integer)
      request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
      String servletName = (String)
      request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");

      if (servletName == null) {
         servletName = "Unknown";
      }
      String requestUri = (String)
      request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");

      if (requestUri == null) {
         requestUri = "Unknown";
      }

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Error/Exception Information";
      String docType =
         "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
         "transitional//en\">\n";

      out.println(docType +
         "<html>\n" +
         "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
         "<body bgcolor = \"#f0f0f0\">\n");

      if (throwable == null && statusCode == null) {
         out.println("<h2>Error information is missing</h2>");
         out.println("Please return to the <a href=\"" + 
            response.encodeURL("http://localhost:8080/") + 
            "\">Home Page</a>.");
      } else if (statusCode != null) {
         out.println("The status code : " + statusCode);
      } else {
         out.println("<h2>Error information</h2>");
         out.println("Servlet Name : " + servletName + "</br></br>");
         out.println("Exception Type : " + throwable.getClass( ).getName( ) + "</br></br>");
         out.println("The request URI: " + requestUri + "<br><br>");
         out.println("The exception message: " + throwable.getMessage( ));
      }
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }

   // Method to handle POST method request.
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      doGet(request, response);
   }
}
```

Where Should I place the above java file ?
I manually had to compile it to class file and place in the  /webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes directory. Please tell me the proper way to handle it.

Comment: I don't see what REST services have to do with UI.  They should be completely decoupled.  The REST service should catch any exceptions and create an appropriate response to return to the user.  If that happens to be rendered in an error page so be it.

Comment: You should place your Java file inside `src/main/java/{package_nname}`

Comment: How can return a custom error xml response in servlet exceptions?